# Trouble Reading from Properties File

Tags: java, junit

I'm building a Java program that will automatically run a hundred or so tests. The program itself is in its final stages of production, and my boss wants me to take out all hard-coded variables and store them in a .properties file. Right now I have two java files Logic.java and Tests.java, and a properties files xxx.properties. However when I run the code (JUnit tests in Tests.java), it appears that the properties never get loaded. Relevant code follows:

In Logic.java

```
Properties properties = new Properties();

String val1;
String val2;
...
String last_val;

public void importProperties() {
  try {
    properties.load(new FileInputStream("xxx.properties"));
    val1 = properties.getProperty("val1-property-name");
    ...
    lastVal = properties.getProperty("lastVal-property-name");
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}

public void test() {
   importProperties();
   //Testing code follows, several method calls referencing val1, val2, etc
}
```

In Tests.java

```
Logic logic = new Logic();

@Before
public void before() {
    logic.importProperties();
}

@Test
public void test1() {
  logic.testMethod();
}

//More tests
```

}

I should be importing the properties and setting the string vals in Logic.java in the @Before method since I'm not creating a new instance of Logic (or so I believe), but when I try to find the values of the strings (writing the string values to a log file), there's no text in said file. I know for a fact that the log file writing works, so the Strings aren't being set to their property values. My property file is also correctly written, I can provide more information if necessary. Thanks!

Edit: So after a bunch of troubleshooting it looks as if the properties file is definitely being read since a properties.keys() call returns all the keys. It's not setting the strings the the key values, however. Still troubleshooting but any ideas would be helpful

Comment: Did you check if the path is correct? `new FileInputStream("xxx.properties")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
properties.load(new FileInputStream("xxx.properties"));
```

with

```
properties.load(new InputStreamReader(Logic.class.getResource("xxx.properties").openStream(), "UTF8"));
```

& test again. I hope it solves your problem

Comment: I've tried your solution several different ways (rearranging imports/method calls) as well as @mprabhat's suggestion but to no avail. I think it's a problem with something else in my program, but I'm not forgetting about your suggestions. If there is anything else you think may be the cause I'd appreciate your feedback, in the meantime I'll periodically stop back here to see any other suggestions and (hopefully be able to) mark one as accepted

Comment: I finally figured out what was wrong! It was a combination of a path typo in my properties file and (after fixing said file) the way I loaded my properties. Your suggestion did the trick finally, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think your properties file is not being found and thats the whole issue.

Instead of creating a new FileInputStream try to use below lines of code

```
properties.load(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("xxx.properties"));
```